# How does the ysl.com homepage's main image have a dynamically changing inset based on viewport width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first post so please forgive me for anything I miss/mess-up.

I've been trying to clone ysl.com (Yves Saint Laurent's website) for practice, and I'm running into difficulty understanding the inset of the main image on their homepage.

When I inspect element, I see that as I narrow and widen the viewport width, the inset of the image dynamically changes to keep that image in the center.

Anyone have an idea of how this is done? Is this something that might be entirely done through CSS? Or is there javascript behind this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: its javascript manually calculating the inset based on the viewport width on resize

Comment: @skara9 Thank you!